# How correctly give vector from function (type_traits)

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, c++14, sfinae

How can I return `std::vector` from this `operator+()`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

template<typename> struct is_std_vector :  std::false_type {};
template<typename T, typename A> struct is_std_vector<std::vector<T, A>> :  std::true_type {};
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_std_vector<std::decay_t<T>>::value>
operator+(T&& vec1, T&& vec2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vec2.size(); ++i)
        vec1.emplace_back(std::forward<int>(vec2.at(i)));
    return vec1;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec1{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    std::vector<int> vec2{ 2,3,4,5,6 };
    std::vector<int> vecResult;
    vecResult = std::move(vec1) + std::move(vec2);
    for (const auto& itr : vecResult)
        std::cout << itr << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

now function return void, but i don't know why, i want give `std::vector` as forward reference to `operator+(T&& vec1, T&& vec2)` and return `std::vector`. I think that is good, but compiler know better. Some suggestions?

error compiler

> C2679 binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand
>   of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Is there a reason youre not taking `std::vector<T>&&` as argument?

Comment: @Borgleader thank i forgot change to vector without my experiments, but problem is the same.

Comment: @Borgleader but `std::vector<T>&&` is rvalue i want forward reference ( I add to discription )

Comment: Why do you require a `vector` specifically? Can't you take any type which has the appropriate interfaces?

Comment: If you take a the first argument by value and move, and the second by const ref (both to std::vector<T>) you should get (near) optimal performance afaict.

Comment: @NicolBolas it's only example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the default type for `std::enable_if_t`, when the condition is true, is `void`.

So, instead of returning `void`

```
std::enable_if_t<is_std_vector<std::decay_t<T>>::value>
   operator+(T&& vec1, T&& vec2)
```

I suppose you should returning `T` or something similar

```
std::enable_if_t<is_std_vector<std::decay_t<T>>::value, T>
   operator+(T&& vec1, T&& vec2)
```